# How to open FaceBook, GoogleMaps or Dialer with business information?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want my app to be able to open facebook or the phone dialer when they click on the contact information in my aboutus.xml
How would i go about doing this? Would i need to make the information buttons that are clickable? I am pretty lost with this

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.vitoriano_vaz.eastbayvapes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

/*
This app is for a local Vape Shop
 it's purpose is to increase customer flow, and provide a menu for Android users

 the array is going to be called = da_menu
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static Intent java;

    /*
    called when the user clicks the send Button
     */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        /*
        This is new so i can send the user to the aboutUs.xml
         once the button on the main menu ( activity_main.xml ) is clicked
         */
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        populateListView();
    }


    private void populateListView() {
        // Create the list of items

        String[] juiceMenu= {
                "#1 BLUEBERRY BOMBSHELL \nBlueberry Dessert",
                "#2 RICHIE RICH\nStrawberry cream",
                "#3 CHIQUITA\nCreamy Banana with a bready after taste",
                "#4 AFTERNOON DELIGHT\nKiwi Strawberry Dessert",
                "#5 POPPIN OTTERS\nMelted OtterPop",
                "#6 VIVA LA SANGRIA\nFruit more Fruit and Wine",
                "#7 OKOLE MALUNA\nPineapple fruit blend",
                "#8 CARMEN MIRANDA\nVanilla custard with a crisp",
                "#9 POMALADE\nIt's Bombalade!",
                "#10 IZUAL\nWhirlwind of icy Fruits",
                "#11 BUTTER STOTCH\nProfessor Chaos will surely get grounded for this one!",
                "#12 BLUE BULLS\nGrab the bull by the horns",
                "#13 GRAPE APE\nA grapple a day will keep the doctor away",
                "#14 BRUCE JUICE\nPerfectly blended old fashioned",
                "#15 DOC HOLIDAY\nN.E.T. Tabacco flavor",
                "#16 PEACHY KEEN\nPeach Cobbler",
                "#17 HULA\nStrawberry coconut ",
                "#18 NEW YORK\nPeppermint paddy dipped in chocolate",
                "#19 AL GORE\nFruit Loops plain and simple",
                "#20 LUX CHARMS\nThey're magically delicious",
                "#21 SAILOR JACK\nCracker Jack",
                "#22 GET HIM TO THE GREEK\nGreek Yogurt with peach",
                "#23 KEY WE LIE CHI\nFruit loving lychee",
                "#24 SPRING FLING\nA trois of honeydew berries ",
                "#25 GUMBY\nsour watermelon gummy",
                "#26 CHAI\nMILK - Milk Chai Tea",
                "#27 MR. BBEAN\nCappuccino cream",
                "#28 50 SHADES OF ORANGE\nDelightful orange cream",
                "#29 BLUE WAFFLES\nBlueberry Waffle",
                "#30 ENIGMA\n Mystery",
                "#31 MR. FREEZE\nPeppermint, Spearmint mainly just minty",
                "#32 CUP OF JOE\nCup of French Vanilla",
                "#33 BON JOVI\nVanilla Bourbon ",
        };
        // Build adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,               // context for the activity
                R.layout.da_menu,   // Layout to create
                juiceMenu);         // Items to be displayed

        //configure list view
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**Information to open other apps**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E3E5E1"
    android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AboutUs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="About Us"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/AboutUs"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:text="eastbay@gmail.com"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:text="1239 N Vasco RD Liver, Ca 94444"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:text="(925)-961-9999"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:text="facebook.com/eastbay"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
        android:text="Instagram: @eastbay"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="Monday - Saturday 10:00 am - 8:00 pm\n Sunday 10:00 am - 6:00 pm" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you should check how to use intent
http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand how to use Intent for example if you want the user to open the Dialer with specific phone number you would do something like below and change it with the number you want

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
startActivity(intent);
```

check this link to understand the intent
http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

otherwise search on stack overflow for specific action

Comment: would this be the same for google maps? 
Also could i or should i leave the layout how it is (EditText) or is there a more efficient layout for this type of data and the purpose it is going to be used for? @Mujtaba Alboori

Comment: you will you need make some modification depend on what app you want to launch. the link contains what parameters you would use to open Google map
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#display_a_map

Comment: @CosmoVitoriano in term layout, I'm not sure what you app does but it is all depend on your usage but this is not very relevant for sending data to other apps like Google maps and facebook. it won't affect the performance.  You could use textview if the user is not interacting with you view.

Comment: it is a menu for a business. The about us is mainly for the user to see the business's contact information

Comment: @CosmoVitoriano TextView is enough instead of EditText. there is good answer below. like I said try to understand what Intent is. Intent is important part of android platform and it used for many things. just search in Stackoverflow or google for answer. and what parameter you need

Answer (score 0):

for facebook,

```
try {

context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/eastbay"));

} catch (Exception e) {

return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/eastbay"));

}
```

for Instagram,

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/eastbay");
Intent likeIng = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

likeIng.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

try {
    startActivity(likeIng);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/eastbay")));
}
```

for email,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "eastbay@gmail.com" });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

for dialer,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9259619999"));
startActivity(intent);
```

for maps,

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=" + yourAddress;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

You should use Google before asking here. Happy Coding!